# Which of the following has highest solubility in water?

Tags: solubility

Which of the following has highest solubility in water?

A. $ Ca(OH)_2 $

B. $ Fe(OH)_3 $

C. $ Cr(OH)_3 $

D. $ Zn(OH)_2 $

And also please explain how can we predict their solubilities when we are not provided with their solubility products.

I know that calcium hydroxide is sparingly soluble. So it cannot be the right option. I think Iron hydroxide is also soluble to a good extent. I haven't got any idea about option C. I think D may be the right answer.

Comment: Hi SkyDreamer welcome to ChemistryS.E.! Can you show us your efforts and your attempts, we can't do your homework see our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange)! :-)

Comment: I know that calcium hydroxide is sparingly soluble. So it cannot be the right option. I think Iron hydroxide is also soluble to a good extent. This is evident as Iron rusts in presence of water vapours, but it is a slow process. I haven't got any idea about option C. I think D may be the right answer.

Comment: Please help! I have got my final exam tomorrow.

Comment: What are your thoughts on what the answer is? We can't solve problems for you; we only guide you through them.

In addition, iron hydroxide is a gel-like substance and is hydrated. I'm not aware of how this gel-like precipitate may rust.

Comment: Ohh. I think I was wrong about Iron hydroxide. I just have got a rough idea that the answer is D.

Comment: I've add to your question your thoughts, and I've retract my close vote!

Comment: OK.. Thank you! But what do you think could be the most probable answer?

Comment: @SkyDreamer9 you are welcome [here is a video to learn it quickly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsCLuLS-yZY) good luck for your exam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't predict solubility reasoning, you have to remember [**solubility rules**](http://www.csudh.edu/oliver/chemdata/solrules.htm) in your case this one:

> 6. Most hydroxide salts are only slightly soluble. Hydroxide salts of Group I elements are soluble. Hydroxide salts of Group II elements (Ca, Sr, and Ba) are slightly soluble. Hydroxide salts of transition metals and $\ce{Al^3+}$ are insoluble. Thus, $\ce{Fe(OH)3, Al(OH)3, Co(OH)2}$ are not soluble.

So in this case $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ even if slightly soluble theoretically should be the right answer.